# Including jsp images within a jsp file

Tags: jsp, scope

I have a page customer.jsp that displays textual information stored within an object called Customer. On that page, I include an image that is generated dynamically based on the information stored in Customer, by including the HTML

```
<img src="cust_image.jsp" />,
```

where cust_image.jsp has content type image/jpeg. What is the best way to make the Customer object available to cust_image.jsp, bearing in mind that the user could have several open instances of customer.jsp displaying different customers' details? Is there a way to avoid postfixing cust_image.jsp with the customer ID?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you've provided enough details about the context to suggest what approach might be the most appropriate.

But some options that come to mind are, instead of placing the image in a file:

1. Use the data scheme, to include the image bytes literally.
2. Use a custom taglib to create and include the image data.